# C# Multiple file attachments with email not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attaching multiple PDF on email not working,When i attached single file its working but when i attached two file i am getting error "**Failure sending mail**"
Below is my code

```
MailMessage objMailMessage = new MailMessage();
objMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from, senderName);
objMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
objMailMessage.Subject = addSub + " " + (string)mailParameters[1];
objMailMessage.Body = (string)mailParameters[2];
objMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = isHTML; 
objMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("my file 1 path"));
objMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("my file 1 path"));
```

Comment: Maybe you faced with size limit of your smtp server? Could you please include a full error message into question?

Comment: I'd assume there's an InnerException that tells you _why_ it failed...

Comment: Maybe you're exceeding the max mail size allowed by the SMTP?

Comment: @Gusman file size is 48KB and 50KB

Comment: @Gusman, when i send Zip with 96KB its working but only one Zip File

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attaching the same file twice ("my file 1 path").  Attach two or more different files